# Error:Variable does not exist: StageName [It is occuring when i am trying to compare old values to new values]

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
public static void opptaskcreation(List<Opportunity> lstoppy)
{
    List<Task> lsttask = new List<Task>();
    for(Opportunity opp :lstoppy)
    {
        if(opp.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName)
        {
            Task tasklist = new Task();
            tasklist.status = 'Not Started';
            tasklist.subject = 'Call';
            tasklist.Priority = 'High';
            tasklist.WhatId = opp.Id;
            tasklist.OwnerId = Userinfo.getUserId();
            lsttask.add(tasklist);
        }
    }
    if(!lsttask.isEmpty())
    {
        insert lsttask;
    }
}
```

Trigger part:

```java
trigger taskoppcreation on Opportunity (after update) 
{
   if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate)
   {
       Accountupdation.opptaskcreation(Trigger.new);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `Opportunity` in your org? If you do, then that would be causing _name shadowing_ which could cause this error. If that's the case, then the fix is to rename that class.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you avoid ever referencing `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.oldMap`, or any other variable from the trigger context outside an `Apex Trigger`. Ideally, you should impelement some trigger handler pattern and pass those variables as needed, but even if you want to call methods from your trigger body, you should still pass these variables as parameters. In addition to consistency with yourself (you already pass `Trigger.new`), passing `Trigger.oldMap` has the benefit that the compiler will know that from an `Apex Trigger` bound to `Opportunity`, it is a `Map<Id, Opportunity>`, whereas from an `Apex Class` it only knows `Map<Id, SObject>`. The trigger context is the only place this sort of conversion will actually compile. If I recall correctly, you can't even cast `Map<Id, SObject>` to `Map<Id, Opportunity>`.

Anyway, that's the reason you get this error. Your `Apex Class` sees `Trigger.oldMap` as a `Map<Id, SObject>`, which means the `Map.get` call gives you back `SObject`, from which you cannot statically reference specific fields unless you use a dynamic `SObject.get` call (other than `Id`). Here's an expanded code demonstration of what you are currently doing:

```
public static void myMethod(List<Opportunity> newRecords)
{
    //...
    Map<Id, SObject> oldMap = Trigger.oldMap;
    SObject oldRecord = oldMap.get(newRecord.Id);
    String stage = oldRecord.StageName;
    //...
}
```

That error is expected. If you instead pass in your `oldMap` as an argument to your method, it becomes:

```
public static void myMethod(List<Opportunity> newRecords, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap)
{
    //...
    Opportunity oldRecord = oldMap.get(newRecord.Id);
    String stage = oldRecord.StageName;
    //...
}
```